# How to count how many times a letter appears in all of the strings of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

```
public static int countLetter(String[] x, String y){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        for(int h = 0; h < x[i].length(); h++){
            String yo = new String(x[i].substring(h,h+1));
            if(yo==y){
                count++;}
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

My method should return an integer that counts how many times total the letter appears in all strings of the array. (Assuming the string is one letter and I can't use charAt()).

Comment: `return (int)Arrays.stream(x).map(Pattern.compile(y, Pattern.LITERAL)::matcher).flatMap(Matcher::results).count();`

Comment: `return Stream.of(x).flatMap(s -> s.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i)).filter(s -> s.equals(y.charAt(0))).count();`

Comment: There is absolutely no need to `new String(..)` a substring (there was in Java 6 and earlier (maybe early Java 7 version as well), but that reason no longer exists).

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you compare strings.

Change

`if(yo==y)`

To

```
if(yo.equals(y))
```

Or if u want to ignore casing of letters

```
if(yo.equalsIgnoreCase(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on String comparison. You need to use `equals()` or maybe `equalsIgnoreCase()` when comparing 2 String in Java:

```
public static int countLetter(String[] x, String y) {
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      for (int h = 0; h < x[i].length(); h++) {
         String yo = new String(x[i].substring(h, h + 1));
         if (yo.equals(y)) {
            count++;
         }
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

You can also do this with a `char` instead of `String`:

```
public static int countLetter(String[] x, char y) {
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      for (int h = 0; h < x[i].length(); h++) {
         if (x[i].charAt(h) == y) {
            count++;
         }
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code on line 6

```
if(yo==y)
```

To

```
if(yo.equals(y))
```

That should be work.